# Presenter pattern implementation

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails

I've recently discovered patterns and decided to implement Presenter pattern inside a pedagogical project. I spent few days playing around with different implementations, reading some Gem's source code.

However, I'm not sure I'm handling delegation and decoration appropriately. Could anyone give me feedback on my implementation?

Through this example I'll describe `BasePresenter` and `CartPresenter < BasePresenter`. You may find it [here](https://gitlab.com/kawsay/stickers-shop/-/blob/54aa793cdd5d2b65078c792e65bcbf1bd1b20a48/app/presenters/cart_presenter.rb) on GitLab if you prefer.

Here's how I did:

---

**BASE PRESENTER**

```rb
class BasePresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  # Dynamically defines a method to access @object
  def self.presents(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end

  # Exposes the @template, allowing usage of helper methods (Drapper's way)
  def h
    @template
  end
```

---

**DISPLAY MODEL's DATA**

Here's a Presenter (`CartPresenter` goal is to summarize itself, and associated `Product` and `CartProduct` inside a `<table>`):

```rb
class CartPresenter < BasePresenter
  presents :cart

  def display_cart_amount(tag: :div, **opts)
    amount = h.number_to_currency(cart_amount)

    h.content_tag tag, class: opts[:class] do
      h.content_tag :strong, amount
    end
  end

  def cart_amount
    cart.amount
  end
```

**Q)** At this point we can already see that `CartPresenter` (as others) needs to embed Model's data into HTML. As it violates the Single Responsibility Principle, do I need something like `Decorators` to take formatted data from Presenters and warp it inside HTML?

---

**DELEGATION**

A `Presenter` may also need to delegate methods to associated `Presenters`

```rb
class CartPresenter < BasePresenter
  ...

#   Returns a tuple of 2 presenters <strike>based on product.id</strike>    
  def delegators 
 => [
#        [<ProductPresenter>, <CartProductPresenter>],
#        [<ProductPresenter>, <CartProductPresenter>],
#        ...
#      ]
    products.zip(cart_products)
  end

  def products
#   => <ProductPresenter>
    cart.products.map { |p| ProductPresenter.new(p, @template) }
  end

  def cart_products
#   => <CartProductPresenter>
    cart.cart_products.map { |cp| CartProductPresenter.new(cp, @template)}
  end
```

**Q)** I'm violating the SRP again. Would you recommend me to refactor this inside `BasePresenter` or to create a `Delegator` abstraction? Also, I used to memoized `:products` and `:cart_products` inside instance variable, but it make no sens as function are called once and data they returns is used directly (right?).

---

**DISPLAY DELEGATORS' DATA**

Here's how I'm using those delegators:

```rb
class CartPresenter < BasePresenter
  ...

  # Display table's rows to summarize delegators data (Product/CartProduct)
  def display_summary
    content = delegators.reduce('') do |c, delegators|
      c << summaries_row(delegators)
    end
    content.html_safe
  end

  def summaries_row(delegators)
    h.content_tag :tr, delegated_summaries(delegators)
  end

  # Each delegators implements ``:summary'' to interface with this method
  def delegated_summaries(delegators)
    content = delegators.reduce('') do |c, delegator|
      c << delegator.summary
    end
    content.html_safe
  end
```

**Q)** `.html_safe` adds injection vulnerabilities right? I could try to rigorously validate data, but is there a way **not** to open that breach? As the `html_safe`'s doc says:

> It is your responsibility to ensure that the string contains no malicious content. [...] It should never be called on user input.

---

**INSTANTIATING PRESENTERS**

To instantite the main Presenter inside a Controller, the second way is the best, right? (as `@cart` is a useless instance variable)

```rb
# Carts Controller

#    1st way
      @cart = Cart.includes(:products, :cart_products, :image_attachments, :blobs).user_cart(current_user)
      render 'carts/show', locals: { presenter: CartPresenter.new(@cart, view_context) }

#    2nd
       cart = Cart.includes(:products, :cart_products, :image_attachments, :blobs).user_cart(current_user)
       @presenter = CartPresenter.new cart, view_context
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At this point we can already see that CartPresenter (as others) needs to embed Model's data into HTML. As it violates the Single Responsibility Principle, do I need something like Decorators to take formatted data from Presenters and warp it inside HTML?

No, HTML belongs in your views. If you need to share HTML, you should create a partial. The presenter pattern wraps methods used in your views in an object to not 'pollute' the presented object and to keep your views more readable. You should not put HTML in your presenter.

In your example, you could have a `CartRow` (or `CartRowPresenter`) class and then a `_cart_row.html.erb` partial.

> Q: Also, I used to memoized :products and :cart_products inside instance variable, but it make no sens as function are called once and data they returns is used directly (right?).

Correct, memoization is "optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls". If you don't use the computation result several times, there is no need to memoization.

> Q: .html_safe adds injection vulnerabilities right? I could try to rigorously validate data, but is there a way not to open that breach?

As mentioned in my first answer, you should avoid putting HTML in your Presenter (Model, PORO, etc). HTML belongs in your views (and helpers).